# Unable to set connection properties - JNDI

Tags: oracle, jdbc, pentaho, jndi, pentaho-data-integration

How can I set the defaultRowPrefetch property for a JNDI data source? Setting it as an option parameter in the transformation has no effect on a JNDI connection. The option parameter works fine for a Native JDBC connection.

Below is how I define the connection in simple-jndi/jdbc.properties file:

```
SampleData/type= javax.sql.DataSource
SampleData/driver= oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
SampleData/url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/oracledb
SampleData/user=user
SampleData/password=password
```

Comment: I don't know simple-jndi, but have you tried using `SampleData/defaultRowPrefetch=<desired value>`

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes, I’ve tried this and it does not work.

Comment: Can you set it in the code as a connection property as shown in the sample? (https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java)